# Export ruby middleware to node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby

I'm trying to write server-side logics for Firebase realtime database. Currently they only have sdk support for node.js, but our team previously only work on Ruby. So I'd love to export a bunch of ruby gems that we wrote before and make it work with the node.js.

I'm thinking if there is a way to export ruby code to node.js code so that it can be executed seamlessly with other node.js code.

Currently I only found this repository, but it seems to be importing ruby interpreter and execute ruby code one line at a time, which is not ideal to me, and the repo seems to be outdated too, last commit was 8 years ago.

https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/node.rb

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: this is kind of silly. Since Node runs on the server there's no reason you can't call Ruby scripts from the Node code. Use a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: @maxpleaner: that's not _seamless_, though. Very obvious seam there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just easily "export" Ruby code to NodeJS code. They're two completely different languages. It's like asking if you can export Java to Javascript, or vice-versa.

Comment: Probably not as simple hitting an "export" button, but there _are_ ruby->js transpilers. [Opal](http://opalrb.com/), for example.

Comment: Of course, there's also [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/), a polyglot virtual machine which allows multiple languages such as Ruby (via TruffleRuby) and JavaScript to be used at the same time.